# Find number in string between spaces and parse it

Tags: python, string, substring, parseint

I have a file with lines in following format:

```
d    55    r:100:10000
```

I would like to find that `55` and parse it to int. How can I do this ? I would like to make it variable-space-in-between-proof. Which means that there might be more or less spaces in between but it will be between `d` and `r` for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method by default splits on arbitrary-width whitespace:

```
>>> 'd    55     r:100:10000'.split()
['d', '55', 'r:100:10000']
```

Picking out just the middle number then becomes a simple select:

```
>>> int('d    55     r:100:10000'.split()[1])
55
```

Quoting the documentation:

> If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.

Comment: Wow, guys you were blazing fast! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

That's easy:

```
number = int(line.split()[1])
```

If you actually need to check whether it's between `d` and `r`, then use

```
import re
number = int(re.search(r"d\s+(\d+)\s+r", line).group(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> line = 'd    55    r:100:10000'
>>> int(line.split()[1]) # By default splits by any whitespace
55
```

Or being more efficient, you can limit it to two splits (where the second one holds the integer):

```
>>> int(line.split(None, 2)[1]) # None means split by any whitespace
55
```